# Command to change Hands Free Telephony setting of a specific device?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, command

I am trying to automate the task of enabling/disabling the Hands Free Telephony service for a specific bluetooth device (headphones).
The normal way I am able to manually do this is by opening "Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Devices and Printers" and then right-click on the device, select "Properties", then on the Properties window that opens, select the "Services" tab, then check/uncheck the "Hands Free Telephony" option.

Searching around, all that seems to come up is commands to modify System services, or posts about manually enabling/disabling the way I described. The closest I have come so far is to open the properties window for specific devices using rundll32.exe from a Microsoft support post (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-invoke-the-device-properties-dialog-box-from-the-application-or-from-a-command-prompt-ca8ba122-ec37-2bbe-432d-6ff831f05fcd). But this is not the same properties window that opens from right-clicking in Devices and Printers.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a better way to change the services properties for a specific device?

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to figure this out, but there is a possibility by using the [Bluetooth Command Line Tools](https://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools):

The tools allow you to disable/enable certain bluetooth services by ID. For the hands free service (HFP) the ID is `111e`, so the "Hands Free Telephony" can be disabled by running

```
btcom -n "WH-1000XM5" -r -s111e
```

Adapt the name (`-n`) to whatever your device name is.

Credits for describing this go to MarcinJ who explained this on a [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1426949/scripting-connecting-disconnecting-a-paired-bluetooth-device#1427536).

Comment: What a blessing! Windows 11 isn't capable of persisting this anymore, so I had to disable it every morning before our meetings. If I joined a call and disabled it I had to restart my headphones. Super annoying. Scheduled this as a logon task in the task scheduler, now I can live a worry free live again :)

Comment: Indeed. There might even be a better trigger: you can listen on Bluetooth connect event by using Log "Microsoft-Windows-Bluetooth-Policy/Operational", Source "Bluetooth-Policy" and Event ID "9". But you need to enable the Log first in the Event Viewer under Windows Logs.

Comment: Since it takes a few seconds to run the command and I usually turn on my headphones and immediately want to join a meeting, I guess logon is the better one for me. No issues then :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a direct way to disable this service, but for me disabling the "Headset (510BT Hands-Free)" related drivers did the trick, I did a disable.cmd to disable the related drivers:

```
powershell -Command "& {$device = Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -eq '510BT Hands-Free AG'}; Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $device.InstanceId -Confirm:$false}"

powershell -Command "& {$device = Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -eq 'Headset (510BT Hands-Free)'}; Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $device.InstanceId -Confirm:$false}"

powershell -Command "& {$device = Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -eq '510BT Hands-Free'}; Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $device.InstanceId -Confirm:$false}"
```

I created a shortcut for disable.cmd and in advanced properties I set it to always run as administrator.

So I created a shortcut on my keyboard using AutoHotKey for when I press Ctrl+9 to run the cmd file:

```
^9::
     Run, "N:\Users\moise\OneDrive\Documents\AEG\Scripts\cmd\disable.cmd.lnk"
return
```